# How to find if an IP range is subrange of a list of IP ranges in KQL

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I am trying to write a KQL query where I want to find if an IP range is subrange of a given list of IP ranges (dynamic array). The functionality is same as [ipv4_is_in_any_range](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/ipv4-is-in-any-range-function)  just that instead of an IP I have an IP range that I want to find to  be subrange of a given list of IP ranges in CIDR notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to find if an IP range is subrange of a list of IP ranges in KQL

You can only check for a single IP address as below:

```
let x = "192.168.1.0/24"; 
let listip = dynamic(["192.168.0.0/16", "10.0.0.0/8", "172.16.0.0/12"]); 
print Present=ipv4_is_in_any_range(x, listip)
```

**`Output:`**

[image]

But if you want to check for a in between range, then you can use below kql query:

```
let x = "192.168.1.0/24 - 192.168.1.1/24";
let listip = dynamic(["192.168.0.0/16", "10.0.0.0/8", "172.16.0.0/12"]); 
let c=split(x,"-");
let Present1 =ipv4_is_in_any_range(tostring(c[0]), listip);
let Present2=ipv4_is_in_any_range(tostring(c[1]), listip);
print Present1 and Present2, Present1, Present2;
```

**`Output:`**

[image]

Here `print_0` is output the range checking and used **`and`** to check both true then true else false.

**`Outside Subrange example:`**

```
192.168.1.0/24 - 192.169.1.0/24
```

**`Output:`**

If the last IP is is not in the list and all other n are in list then also it should give false and it has given

[image]

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/SampleMetrics?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA4WOQQqDMBBF9z1FyCpCjEkQaxHv0L1ICBpkwKbBhKK3b6ol1FWZzcyf//7MbAJaUYuwuEkmqpoJxgtZohydBdxc5midwQdw0T9uVj9gIF0CefSJCtMYxdleRb1P18/%20WEvcZw3ak4bWuxkCWSnOcXak3xfjjQ0CteBepQKvwCptN7VoOxkSnj4sYCcydLzP6PeZMyv/ouKEuqj%20HNZ2TEk0yamTzRtbZOnIMAEAAA==).

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful. The name of the function is little unclear that it supports finding a range and not just a single ip.